# d3 Zoom event undefinedWhy does the 'event' parameter appear as 'undefined' in my event handler function when using the d3.zoom() function in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm implementing zoom functionality on an SVG chart using D3.js. However, when using the d3.zoom() function and the zoomed(event) function, the 'event' parameter is showing as 'undefined' in the console.
Here's my code:

```
const container = svg.append('g');
const zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
.on('zoom', zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed(event) {
console.log('hello', event);
container.attr('transform', event.transform);
```

I have verified that I'm using the latest version of D3.js and that other D3.js functions and features are working correctly in my code. Is there something I'm missing or any additional setup I should be aware of to ensure that the event parameter is available and not undefined in my zoomed function?

I appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: What's the D3 version you use?